# Django-invitations email template

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using [django-invitations](https://github.com/bee-keeper/django-invitations) to manage user invitation.
I can't find where I should put the template files `email_invite_message.txt` and `email_invite_subject.txt`

[Here](https://github.com/bee-keeper/django-invitations/issues/138) they talk about

> Override email_invite_message.txt in django-invitations/invitations/templates/invitations/email/.
> You can do this by creating the file in the same directory path in your project.

or

> Yeah, if this isn't clear, you can create an .html file in your project at {projectroot}/{app}/templates/invitations/email/email_invite_message.html and it will override the default template.

But the first one didn't work for me and I can't figure out what {app} should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override any third-party application templates by creating replacement files in your project’s templates directory as indicated in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/overriding-templates/) here.

In your settings.py file edit the TEMPLATES var, specifically the 'DIRS' key

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

...

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR + '/core/templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

let's suppose you have an app named core, edit the settings as in the previous example and put the new files in this way (for this particular app):

```
core/
    /templates
        /invitations
            /email
                email_invite_message.html
                email_invite_subject.html
    __init__.py
    admin.py
    apps.py
    models.py
    tests.py
```

Comment: It still doens't work. How does the plugin know that it has to look inside `core` app ?

Comment: the dirs value in the TEMPLATES var

Comment: Thank you I managed to make it work. The correct path is `core/templates/invitations/email/email_invite_*`. If you want to edit your answer I'll mark it as accepted.